# My first try to output my Drupal7 module as a custom block failed

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

This is my first try to create a Drupal module: Hello World.

I need it to have it displayed as a custom block and I found this can be implemented by 2 Drupal7 hooks: hook_block_info() and hook_block_view() inside my my helloworld module. In Drupal 6 was used the deprecated hook_block().

In the actual form it works but it only display the text: 'This is a block which is My Module'. I actually need to display the output of my main function: helloworld_output(), the t variable.

```
<?php
        function helloworld_menu(){
          $items = array();
            //this is the url item
          $items['helloworlds'] = array(
            'title'            => t('Hello world'),
            //sets the callback, we call it down
            'page callback'    => 'helloworld_output',
            //without this you get access denied
            'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          );

          return $items;
        }

        /*
        * Display output...this is the callback edited up
        */
        function helloworld_output() {
          header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
          header('Content-Disposition: inline');
          $h = 'hellosworld';
          return $h;
        }

        /*
        * We need the following 2 functions: hook_block_info() and _block_view() hooks to create a new block where to display the output. These are 2 news functions in Drupal 7 since hook_block() is deprecated.
        */
    function helloworld_block_info() {
      $blocks = array();
      $blocks['info'] = array(
        'info' => t('My Module block')
      );

      return $blocks;
    }

    /*delta si used as a identifier in case you create multiple blocks from your module.*/
    function helloworld_block_view($delta = ''){
       $block = array();
       $block['subject'] = "My Module";
       $block['content'] = "This is a block which is My Module";
       /*$block['content'] = $h;*/

        return $block;
    }
    ?>
```

All I need now is to display the content of my main function output: helloworld_output() inside the block: helloworld_block_view().

Do you have an idea why $block['content'] = $h won't work? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

`$h` is a variable local to the `helloworld_output()` function so wouldn't be available in `helloworld_block_view()`.

I'm not sure why you're setting headers in `helloworld_output()`, you should remove those lines as they will only cause you problems.

After you've removed the two calls to `header()` in that function simply change your line of code in the `helloworld_block_view()` function to this:

```
$block['content'] = helloworld_output();
```

And the content you set to `$h` in `helloworld_output` will be put into the block's content region.

Comment: Thanks Clive, It actuallty works as a charm. I think this is a good start in developing modules.